# Query needs editing to allow multiple inserts

Tags: sql, mysqli, sql-insert

I have a table in my database with coaches, and I've configured it to add multiple rows of the sports table into ONE users records.

I'm trying to configure the database so that I can have multiple coaches be inserted at once.

For example, my current query is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO sports (coach, player1, player2, player3, player4)
SELECT 'maddon', player1, player2, player3, player4 game 
FROM sports
WHERE coach IN (SELECT id 
                FROM coach_names 
                WHERE coach IN 'pinella','zimmer');
```

What I want to do is something that will produce the following result:

```
INSERT INTO sports (coach, player1, player2, player3, player4)
SELECT ('maddon','hernandez','larkin'), player1, player2, player3, player4 game 
FROM sports 
WHERE coach IN (SELECT id 
                FROM coach_names 
                WHERE coach IN 'pinella','zimmer');
```

I know the syntax of the last statement is off - just trying to illustrated what I want to accomplish. I'd prefer to do this with just one query.

What I'm doing is basically cloning another coaches players.

Any assistance is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Select and unify your values as a sub table, and join it with the `sports` table (here the MySQL version):

```
INSERT INTO sports (coach, player1, player2, player3, player4)
     SELECT new_coach.name, player1, player2, player3, player4  
       FROM sports, (SELECT 'maddon'    AS name UNION
                     SELECT 'hernandez' AS name UNION
                     SELECT 'larkin'    AS name) as new_coach
      WHERE coach IN (SELECT id 
                        FROM coach_names 
                       WHERE coach IN ('pinella','zimmer'));
```

See this [MySQL demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff1c9/1) or this [Oracle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8d972/1).